# Rename images by date with correct time

Tags: linux, rename, exif

I'd like to rename my images according to their date in EXIF information, BUT with a twist: the date in the EXIF information of one camera brand (the one named panasonic) is off by one hour (it should be one hour sooner).

How can I do this in Linux? I have tried using exiftool as mentioned here : [Sort and rename images by date in EXIF info](https://superuser.com/questions/205417/sort-and-rename-images-by-date-in-exif-info), but this one hour offset really bugs me, and I am not good enough in scripts or programmation to do it by myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `exiftool -alldates-=1 -if '$make eq "Panasonic"' <your dir with photos>`, then follow the guide you linked

Comment: Thanks, it works. If I may also add a completary question: Would it also be possible to append "-panasonic" to all filenames whose picture was taken with this camera brand ?

Comment: Get the "if" part from the line above, add it to the command you used to change file names, and insert `-panasonic` before perdiod (dot, full stop) in the date format string (the one after `-d`)