# Rename image depending on exif

Tags: linux, rename, exif

Using exiftool, would it be possible to append "-panasonic" to all filenames whose picture was taken with this camera brand ? 
For example, a filename 01_01_15.jpg becomes 01_01_15-panasonic.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: In Windows, it can be done with a PowerShell script, http://blog.cincura.net/233463-renaming-files-based-on-exif-data-in-powershell/. Can Wine run PowerShell?

Comment: Please see [this](http://superuser.com/a/991514/458082). @DrMoishePippik, I believe Perl is enough for the task ;-)

Comment: @SalvoF: that is a good answer; I suggest you enter it as such so that it may be accepted.